# Solve the Recurrence relation : $a_n= (a_{n-1})^3a_{n-2}$ , $a_0=1, a_1=3$

Tags: combinatorics, recurrence-relations

$a_n= (a_{n-1})^3a_{n-2}$  , $a_0=1, a_1=3$

I'm ask to get an expression for $a_n$.

So i tried to solve with induction:

$a_n=(a_{n-1})^3a_{n-2}=(a_{n-1})^3(a_{n-3})^3a_{n-4}=(a_{n-1})^3(a_{n-3})^3(a_{n-5})^3 \ldots (a_1)^3a_0$

So $a_n= \prod _{k=1}^n a_{n-k}$ , 
(k is an odd number, so all odd numbers from 1 to n)

Is this the expression? i feel like this is still a reccurence relation, solving with the methods of linear-homog will not work cause this relation is non-linear.

any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Hint: Show that $a_n>0$ for all $n$, and put $u_n=\log a_n$.

Comment: Using the hint by @Kelenner, you have it quickly by some inference method (of frequency tranformation, i.e. $\mathcal{Z}$) and then reversing it. To assure you of your calculations, the final form should look like this $$3^{\frac{ 2^{-n}}{\sqrt{13}}  \left[\left(3+\sqrt{13}\right)^n - \left(3-\sqrt{13}\right)^n \right]}.$$

Comment: @Kelenner thanks! i got it right!!